# Spark executor on yarn-client does not take executor core count configuration.

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

Irrespective of the spark executor core count, yarn container for the executor does not use more than 1 core.

Comment: Can you post a working example?

Comment: Here is the spark configuration:

Comment: Here is the spark configuration: spark.executor.cores=2 and spark.executor.instances=5. Number of executors started in yarn is 5 but each of them only uses 1 core. Spark properties in driver UI does show executor core as 2 but in Yarn UI, it shows using 1 core per container(executor).

Answer (score 11):

YARN is showing 1 core per executor irrespective of `spark.executor.cores` because by default [DefaultResourceCalculator](https://apache.googlesource.com/hadoop-common/+/e0c9f893b684246feb5b4adbb95a05a436cdb790/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/util/resource/DefaultResourceCalculator.java) is used. It considers only memory.

```
public int computeAvailableContainers(Resource available, Resource required) {
// Only consider memory
return available.getMemory() / required.getMemory();
  }
```

Use DominantResourceCalculator, It uses both cpu and memory.

Set below config in `capacity-scheduler.xml`

```
yarn.scheduler.capacity.resource-calculator=org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DominantResourceCalculator
```

More about [DominantResourceCalculator](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~matei/papers/2011/nsdi_drf.pdf)

Comment: Thank You Shekhar. It really helped.

Comment: Man, thanks a lot. You've saved me a ton of time =)