# Apache Spark: How to force usage of certain number of cores?

Tags: azure, apache-spark

I want to run spark-shell in yarn mode with a certain number of cores.

the command I use is as follows

```
spark-shell --num-executors 25 --executor-cores 4 --executor-memory 1G \
--driver-memory 1G --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=2048 --master yarn \
--conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=10G  \
--conf spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KyroSerializer \
-i input.scala
```

`input.scala` looks something like this

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream

// Plaintext sum on 10M rows
def aggrMapPlain(iter: Iterator[Long]): Iterator[Long] = {
   var res = 0L
while (iter.hasNext) {
    val cur = iter.next
    res = res + cur
}
List[Long](res).iterator
 }

val pathin_plain = <some file>

val rdd0 = sc.sequenceFile[Int, Long](pathin_plain)
val plain_table = rdd0.map(x => x._2).cache
plain_table.count

0 to 200 foreach { i =>
    println("Plain - 10M rows - Run "+i+":")
    plain_table.mapPartitions(aggrMapPlain).reduce((x,y)=>x+y)
   }
```

On executing this the Spark UI first spikes to about 40 cores, and then settles at 26 cores.

On recommendation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29940711/apache-spark-setting-executor-instances-does-not-change-the-executors) I changed the following in my `yarn-site.xml`

```
<property>                                                                                                          
       <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores</name>                                                                 
        <value>101</value>
</property>

<property>                                                                                                          
    <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores</name>                                                             
   <value>101</value>                                                                                                
 </property>

<property>                                                                                                          
      <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>                                                                 
       <value>102400</value>                                                                                             
</property>

<property>                                                                                                          
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>                                                                  
    <value>102400</value>                                                                                             
</property>
```

But I still cannot force spark to use 100 cores, which I need as I am doing benchmarking against earlier tests.

I am using Apache Spark 1.6.1. 
Each node on the cluster including the driver has 16 cores and 112GB of memory.
They are on Azure (hdinsight cluster).
2 driver nodes + 7 worker nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unfamiliar with Azure, but I guess YARN is YARN, so you should make sure that you have

```
yarn.scheduler.capacity.resource-calculator=org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DominantResourceCalculator
```

in `capacity-scheduler.xml`.

(See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33248108/spark-executor-on-yarn-client-does-not-take-executor-core-count-configuration/33251611#33251611) similar question and answer)

Comment: Thank you, I have made that edit to my `capacity-scheduler.xml` but still no change. Currently, to get around this I am setting `--num-executors` to 100 which gives me 101 cores in the Spark UI.

Comment: After making some edits here and there and rewriting some of my code, I have managed to solve the issue. I changed so many things, I'm not sure which one worked but this definitely helped.

Comment: @Sood I realize this is a very old thread, but would you mind sharing your final configs?

Comment: @maverik sorry, but I no longer have access to the codebase.